# mysql, how to ignore part of parameters?

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I have this sententce
`SELECT FROM * Foods`

And I am trying to attach a conditional statement according to what the user filters in the app.

For instance, I'm trying to create a filter for price and taste (sweet, salty) and region.

But the problem is that the user may not set the region or price. But `WHERE price = null` doesn't work because having a null value and not calling price filter by the user are two different things.

Is three a walk around? I want the statement to be reusable as much as possible. I'm new to rdbms, so I'd like to hear some methods Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you build the query dynamically, afterall the query is just a text string until you execute it

Comment: @RiggsFolly is that called dynamic query? The way I think is, if there is a value in the router request params let b = `AND price > 20` is a best so original let a += b; execute(a); is this best? Could u show please?

Comment: Basically `sql = 'SELECT FROM * Foods'; if (price exists) { sql .= ' and price = ?';}`

Comment: Technically all SQL queries are dynamic queries the way people use SQL today. They are all parsed from a string at runtime. The non-dynamic queries were called "embedded SQL," parsed during compilation. Hardly anyone uses SQL that way anymore.

Comment: Do you plan to use Raw Query from Prisma? Can't you just add conditional where clauses in Prisma to achieve this?

Comment: @NurulSundarani Hi, it is because of Geo Queries.. I do not want use Raw Query either.. haha